# CSS libraries don't work when i import into scss file

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome

so am using sass in my npm and gulp based web project. i have an scss file where i import other partials and also CSS libraries like font-awesome.css, which i didn't install with npm..

```
 /**style.scss**/
@import "_partialfile";
@import "../lib/font-awesome";
```

the scss file is to be transpiled to ***style.css*** which i've referenced from my ***index.html*** as the main stylesheet.
My problem is, when i add an icon like `<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>` in the index.html, it doesn't display. Can someone help please...

Comment: which version do u use for font awesome? some version uses fas

Comment: I've tried fas,far,fab,fa all not working

Comment: Try importing files with their extensions.

Comment: Yeah i've tried this @import "../lib/font-awesome.css" it still didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

Well i couldn't find the answer here..but i figured it out myself.
The libraries refused working because a library like font-awesome when installed using npm, moves to npm_modules, as expected, but the folder of the main stylesheet.css references to yet another webfonts folder in ../parent directory. And when i @import the stylesheet into my scss file in my src folder, it looses the reference because I've imported it into another directory where it can't find the webfonts folder....to solve the issue, i simply  copied the webfonts folder to my src directory